# Get all possible combinations of lists and save it in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, permutation, python-itertools

I need help with the following problem:

I have a list and I want to get all possible combinations of this list (but not mixing up the order of the items of the sublists nor mixing the items of one sublist with another). So this is my code so far:

```
my_list = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
print("my list is", my_list)
for x in itertools.permutations(my_list):
    y = list(x)
    print(y)
print("out of the loop y is", y)
```

Output:

```
my list is [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
y is [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
y is [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x'], ['z', 't', 'z']]
y is [['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
y is [['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
y is [['k', 't', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z']]
y is [['k', 't', 'x'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
out of the loop y is [['k', 't', 'x'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

As you can see I do the combinations I want to get if I print the `y` in the loop but as it also makes sense out of the loop only the last list is kept in memory for `y`

How can I keep all the combinations in memory?

The expected goal of the code is that a new list will be generated later on and it needs to check whether the new list is one of those combinations of `y`. So:

```
...
new_list = [['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
if new_list in y:
     print("Yeah! new_list is one of the combinations of my_list")
else:
     print("Oops! Try again!")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your list of permutation in [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as follow:

```
>>> [list(p) for p in itertools.permutations(my_list)]

[[['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']],
 [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x'], ['z', 't', 'z']],
 [['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']],
 [['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'z']],
 [['k', 't', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z']],
 [['k', 't', 'x'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]]
```

Your code could looks like:

```
my_list = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
print('My list: {}'.format(my_list))

all_permutations = [list(p) for p in itertools.permutations(my_list)]
for p in all_permutations:
    print('Possible permutation: {}'.format(p))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to declare `y` as a list and append new lists to that:

```py
y = []
my_list = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
print("my list is", my_list)
for x in itertools.permutations(my_list):
    y.append(list(x))
    print(y)
print("out of the loop y is", y)
```

Now with your last snippet:

```
new_list = [['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
if new_list in y:
     print("Yeah! new_list is one of the combinations of my_list")
else:
     print("Oops! Try again!")
```

You get:

```
Yeah! new_list is one of the combinations of my_list
```

Your code can even be more pythonic if instead of using a loop you use lists comprehension as shown on other answers.

You can replace:

```
for x in itertools.permutations(my_list):
    y.append(list(x))
    print(y)
```

With:

```
y = [list(x) for x in itertools.permutations(my_list)]
```

And get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this more efficiently without the unnecessary calls to `append()` in a few lines of code.

```
import itertools
my_list = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]

y = [list(x) for x in itertools.permutations(my_list)]
print("out of the loop y is", y)

new_list = [['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']]
if new_list in y:
     print("Yeah! new_list is one of the permutations of my_list")
else:
     print("Oops! Try again!")
```

Code Output:

```
out of the loop y is [[['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']], [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x'], ['z', 't', 'z']], [['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x']], [['z', 't', 'z'], ['k', 't', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'z']], [['k', 't', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['z', 't', 'z']], [['k', 't', 'x'], ['z', 't', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]]
Yeah! new_list is one of the permutations of my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert the generator into a list:

`list(itertools.permutations(my_list))`